# Using Javascript how to get numbers in a sorted order array from an alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, how can I write a function which accepts one parameter: a string of unknown length, containing both characters and members. The function should identify the numbers within the string input and store them as the appropriate numeric/non-string data types in an array sorted in ascending order, then return that array.

e.g., input: "AC*WV12n/:e123we2.45oinfwoi6n#a98nfwb+owi"

Output should be [2.45, 6, 12, 98, 123]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getValue(input){
    const a=input.match(/([0-9].[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/g)
  return a.sort((a,b)=>Number(a)>Number(b)?1:-1)

}

const a = getValue("AC*WV12n/:e123we2.45oinfwoi6n#a98nfwb+owi")
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Hi Murhaf. The answer is perfect but the decimal is not showing up for 2.45.  I tried to use parseFloat but didn't worked.